# How to compare a selected row in Workbook1/Sheet3 with a selected row in Workbook2/Sheet3

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first time posting here. I have only been developing in VBA for about 6 months now. I have not found anything similar to my exact needs. I have tried modifying other VBA code I found here and Google to no avail.  I have been working on this problem for 4 days so far and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Workbook1 = the template workbook, Workbook2 = my WIP workbook.
The data I need to analyse is on Sheet3 in both workbooks, if it matters.

My task is to use the template workbook to update my WIP workbook.

What I would like to do is select an entire row in Workbook1 and select an entire row in Workbook2. If any of the data in the cells between columns 1 and 99 are different, I want to automatically insert the ENTIRE row from Workbook1 into Workbook2, just below the selected row in Workbook2.

The data in these rows can include text, numeric, alphanumeric and standard keyboard symbols ($, %, etc.,)

I'm sorry that I don't have any code to show you, I have not found anything relevant to start with. I also can not share my workbook due to it's confidential nature.

Thank you for any help you can provide. Hopefully I provided enough information here to explain my problem.

Comment: With 99 columns and different data types you will probably need to loop through each column and compare the cell contents instead of comparing the entire row at once.

Comment: Create a unique key for each row, create two arrays, for each sheet3, and loop to find the differences.

Comment: Warcupine, Error 404, thank you for the responses. The template is a shared document and is highly regulated, so adding keys to it is not really an option. Plus that document is updated all the time. New rows are often added in between existing rows. Sometimes I need these new rows, sometimes I don't, but that is not part of my request.

Comment: Let me change the meaning my statement above "Sometimes I need these new rows, sometimes I don't, but that is not part of my request." I suppose if I can develop a macro that does as I requested in my original post, it would still add the "New" selected row even if nothing in the selected rows matched. That would work well for me. I will try to come up with some code and post to get things started.

Answer (score 0):

Looping through the data cell by cell is how this would get done.

```
x = 1 'first row of data
n = 10 'last row of data, could be 100 for all I know
y = 1 'first column of data
z = 10 'last column of data, could be 100 for all I know

Do While x <= n
y = 1 'reset the value of y
    Do While y <= z

    If Workbooks(a).Sheets("Sheet3").cells(x, y) <> Workbooks(b).Sheets("Sheet3").cells(x, y) Then
    MsgBox "Found the error in row " & x & " and column " & y & ".", VbOKOnly
    'Do something else...
    else
    End If
    y = y + 1 'go to the next column
    Loop
x = x + 1 'go to the next row
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sub compareandcopy()
dim source as worksheet
dim target as worksheet
set source = workbooks("nameoftemplate").worksheets(3)
set target = workbooks("my wip file").worksheets(3)
dim x as integer
dim y as integer
dim i as integer
' source.Activate
' x = Selection.Row
' target.Activate
' y = Selection.Row

'Using InputBox
x = cint(inputbox("enter row number in source"))
y = cInt(InputBox("Enter row number in target")) 'input box returns variant - y expects integer
for i = 1 to 99
if source.cells(x,i)<>target.cells(y,i) then
    target.rows(y+1).insert
    source.rows(x).copy target.cells(y+1,1)
    exit for
end if
next i
end sub
```

Comment: Harassed Dad, This almost gets me there. Can you add .InputBoxes  so I can select the rows I want to compare? I tried to do this on my own and post it here but I couldn't figure out how to properly post the code. I am getting a Type Mismatch error.

Comment: After more testing I realized it doesn't always find the differences, and if it does, it adds the same line from source 4 times in the target.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CompareRowsAndCopy1()

Dim source As Worksheet
Dim target As Worksheet

Set source = Workbooks("Template.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet3")
Set target = Workbooks("WIP Workbook.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet3")
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim i As Integer

source.Activate
x = CInt(source.Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select row to compare in 
template ", Type:=1))
'MsgBox x


target.Activate
y = CInt(target.Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select row to compare in WIP 
Workbook ", Type:=1))
'MsgBox y

For i = 1 To 99 ' This indicates which columns to compare.
    If source.Cells(x, i) <> target.Cells(y, i) Then
        target.Rows(y + 1).Insert
        source.Rows(x).Copy target.Cells(y + 1, 1)
    Else
    MsgBox ("No differences found in row " & y)

Exit For
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Here is what I tried with Harassed Dads code. I get a type mismatch error.

Comment: Application.inputbox does not have anything in front of it, and should be type 1 not 8 - set x = application.inputbox("",1)